# reading a dat file and adding numbers to array

Tags: c, arrays, file

My program requires me to read a dat file with a list of numbers. My goal is to get each number and add them to an array. The file has around 100 numbers in this format:

> 1
>
> 2
>
> 3

(styling is a bit off sorry ;[ )

so far i have

```
int main()
{
    double prices[1000];
    int count,price;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("price.dat","r");
    if(file == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: can't open file to read\n");
    }
    else
    {   
        printf("File prices.dat opened successfully to read\n");
    }
    if (file){
        while (fscanf(file, "%d", &price)!= NULL){
            count++;
            prices[count]=price;
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Problem is that it continues adding the last number continuously. Any help?

Comment: `fscanf` will never return NULL. Please check the return value in [the documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fscanf.html).

Comment: instead of `null` use `EOF` and that should be it. Also, set your count to 0 instead of leaving it to randomly pick up some memory byte.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems in your code. To name a few:

- `fscanf` doesn't return a pointer so you shouldn't be comparing it with `NULL`. All `scanf` functions returns an integer which can be positive, zero or negative.
- You don't initialize `count` so it will contain a seemingly random value.
- Indexing of arrays starts a zero, so you should not increase the array index `count` until after the assignment.

The actual problem with not wanting to stop is because of the first point.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I am still having trouble understanding what the while loop should equal or not equal to. What should I be comparing it to?

Comment: @dLiGHT Read a [`fscanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) reference, especially the section about its return value.

Comment: I've read it and understand that it returns the number of values it encounters, 0 if it ends early, or EOF if it ends before first matching failure. I must be an idiot for not seeing what the statement is suppose to not equal to ;[

Comment: @dLiGHT Loop while it returns larger than zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PRICES_LIST_MAX      1000
#define PRICES_FILE          "price.dat"

int main()
{
    double prices[PRICES_LIST_MAX];
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(PRICES_FILE,"r");
    if(!file)
    {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return -1;
    }

    memset(prices, 0, sizeof(prices));
    while (!feof(file)               /* Check for the end of file*/
        &&(count < PRICES_LIST_MAX)) /* To avoid memory corruption */
    {
        fscanf(file, "%lf", &(prices[count++]));
    }
    fclose(file);

    /* Print the list */
    printf("Prices count: %d\n", count);
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        printf("Prices[%d] = %lf\n", i, prices[i]);
        }

        return 0;
}
```